# Class Not Found in my Jar File

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have the following code in a HTML page

```
        <applet code="com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain"
            archive="SignedFingerprintSDKJava.jar, AbrirAplicativoAssinado.jar"
            width="515" height="560">
        </applet>
```

When I run my html page, a got an error that says, `"ClassNotFoundException, FormMain.class"`

I run jarscan and I found the class FormMain in my jar file.

What happened ?

**This is how I generate my jar file**

```
jar cvf C:\Users\lucas\desktop\AbrirAplicativo.jar C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\AppletInstaller.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\ColorPane.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\FormMain.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\FormOptions.class C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\Util.class
```

**Generate keys**

```
keytool -genkey -dname "cn=AbrirAplicativoApplet, ou=XXX, o=XXX, l=São Paulo, s=SP c=BR" -alias AbrirAplicativoAppletKey -keystore C:\ChaveAbrirAplicativoApplet -storepass 123456 -validity 7300
```

**Assign Jar File**

```
jarsigner -keystore C:\users\lucas\desktop\ChaveAbrirAplicativoApplet -storepass 123456 -signedjar "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\AbrirAplicativoAssinado.jar" "C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\AbrirAplicativo.jar" AbrirAplicativoAppletKey
```

**Exporting Certificate**

```
keytool -export -keystore C:\users\lucas\desktop\ChaveAbrirAplicativoApplet -alias AbrirAplicativoAppletKey -file C:\users\lucas\desktop\CertificadoAbrirAplicativoApplet.x509
```

**Verifying Assign**

```
keytool -import -alias AbrirAplicativoAppletKey -file C:\CHAVES\CertificadoAbrirAplicativoApplet.x509
```

Maybe my problem are in the `PolicyTool`

When I try to put a new policy entry I got the following error

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: AbrirAplicativoAssinado.jar
```

but how can I put a URL in this field,  if my jar file are in my desktop ?

I try to put `http://localhost/AbrirAplicativoAssinado.jar` but occurs a new error

```
There is not a public key for the alias AbrirAplicativoAppletKey.
```

Comment: Copy/paste the result of `jar -tvf the.jar` where `the.jar` is the Jar in which the the class is.  I agree this has nothing to do with signing.  Save some space and edit that info. out.

Comment: Can what be your manifest?  More words are better than less, as I don't like playing '20 questions'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the “class not found” should have nothing to do with signing. I take it that the jar files reside in the same directory as the html file?

There might be a problem with the way you list multiple archives. You might try the following approaches:

- Omit the `,` from the archive list, leaving just the space.
- Replace the `,` (including the space) by either `:` or `;`.
- Create a jar file which only contains a manifest, and in that manifest add a `Class-Path` property listing the other two archives, separated by a space. Use that file as the `archive=` parameter.
- Modify one of your jar files to reference the other in the `Class-Path` property of its manifest, and only list that one in the `archive=` parameter.

It also apepars as if the way you build yor jar file, all the class files would be placed in the root directory of the file, without internal directory structure. The directory structure in the jar file has to match the package structure of your classes, i.e. the `package` lines in your source code, and also the `code=` parameter of your `applet` tag.

In order to create the directory structure inside your jar file, change directory to `C:\Users\lucas\workspace\applet-chave\bin` and then execute `jar cvf C:\Users\lucas\desktop\AbrirAplicativo.jar com` to add the whole directory `com` to the archive.

Comment: If I put in my tag Applet just FormMain in my code propertie, occurs the Exception NoClassDefFoundError, FormMain (wrong name: com/griaule/fingerprintsdk/appletsample/FormMain). I put all the created files in the same directory

Comment: OK, the exception means that the java plugin now is able to open file `FormMain.class` directly inside the jar, but will refuse to load it as the file states that it should belong to a package `com…sample` instead. So restore the html to what it was before, and create your jar with a directory structure.

Comment: but the Jar command, I just can run through the java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin directory, where I can found the jar command. When I execute outside this direcotrt, occurs the error that 'jar' is not recognized as a intern command

Comment: Sounds like you would want to add the java bin directory to your `PATH` environment variable. Or call `jar` by giving its full path.

Comment: Or use ant to build your java stuff.

Comment: Sorry, was just add in PATH. Well, I done that. In the bin of my applet I execute jar cvf. Now I can just execute the HTML ? or need to do again the assignature ?

Comment: Try it. If it works, it works, otherwise we'll see what doesn't.

Comment: Well, I try to do again, but occurs the same problem. NoClassDefFoundError when I put just FormMain in code propertie, and ClassNotFoundException when I put the whole path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14140/discussion-between-lucas-santos-and-mvg)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `FormMain` somewhere on your `.html` page when what you should be specifying is `com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain`

All that signing stuff you put in your question is pretty irrelevant to a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I am not sure you are building the `.jar` correctly either, it is probably including your user path as well as the Eclipse working directory in the `.jar`. It would be better to take the time to set up Maven to build the `.jar` or at least use the tool built into Eclipse to export the `.jar`, that way you are sure it is being built correctly. Doing it by hand is open to all kinds of mistakes.

Comment: In my html page, is just html body and the tag applet. My tag applet is like what I said, code="com.griaule.fingerprintsdk.appletsample.FormMain". It's just a simple html page to test my applet.

Comment: In Eclipse should be Export as JAR File ?